# Relating two models with same field value?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django, so I apologize a head of time if my verbiage is off. But I'll try my best!
I have two models :

- PlayerProfile - this is updated once a day.
- PlayerListing - this is updated every 5 minutes.

Here are simplified versions of those models.

```
class PlayerProfile(models.Model):
    listings_id = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    card_id = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    overall = models.IntegerField()

class PlayerListing(models.Model):
    listings_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    buy = models.IntegerField()
    sell = models.IntegerField()
```

Currently, we just make queries based on the matching listings_id - but I'd like to have a more traditional relationship setup if possible.
How do you relate two models that have the same value for a specific field (in this case, the listings_id)?

Some potentially relevant information:

- Data for both models is brought in from an external API, processed and then saved to the database.
- Each PlayerListing relates to a single PlayerProfile. But not every PlayerProfile will have a PlayerListing.
- When we create PlayerListings (every 5 minutes), we don't necessarily have access to the correct PlayerProfile model. listings_id's are generated last (as we have to do some extra logic to make sure they're correct).

Comment: Please use foreign key.

Comment: @RiyasAc can you elaborate? it's a one-to-one relationship. And we don't necessarily have access to the correct PlayerProfile model. listings_id's are generated last (as we have to do some extra logic to make sure they're correct).

Comment: Please add sample data for clearing this question.